# firebase data fetching running Inequality query using where clause throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hey I am building a nodejs backend with firebase firestore

and i get this error,

this is the error block I get error on my collection reference

```
Error getting nearest vendor: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: requestStatus and g.geohash

    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:78:8
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:4:12)
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:64:47
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
Error getting nearest vendor: TypeError: geoCollection.orderBy is not a function
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:78:8
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:4:12)
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\src\app.ts:64:47
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\discountlo_backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

here is my route code in nodejs I use firebase admin SDK

```
// Route to get the nearest vendor
app.get("/nearest-vendor", async (req, res) => {
  const { latitude, longitude } = req.query;

  if (!latitude || !longitude) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Latitude and longitude are required" });
  }

  // Create a GeoCollection reference
  const geoCollection = geoFirestore.collection("vendors");

  try {
    const query = geoCollection.where("requestStatus", "!=", "Pending").near({
      center: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(
        parseFloat(latitude as string),
        parseFloat(longitude as string)
      ),
      radius: 100000, // Adjust the radius as needed
    });

    const nearestVendorSnapshot = await query.limit(5).get();

    if (nearestVendorSnapshot.empty) {
      return res.status(404).json([]);
    }

    const nearestVendor: any = [];
    nearestVendorSnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      const {
        coordinates: { _latitude, _longitude },
        ...vendorWithoutLocation
      } = doc.data();
      nearestVendor.push({
        ...vendorWithoutLocation,
        location: { lat: _latitude, long: _longitude },
      });
    });

    return res.json(nearestVendor);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error getting nearest vendor:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

please if anyone can help me with the solution, here i am using geofirestore package to fetch nearest documents based longitude and latitude along with i also need to run another where inequality clause

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? I don't see any reference to `orderBy` in what you've shown.

Comment: I get this error when I used orderBy with geoCollection before where as orderBy('requestStatus')

Comment: Your question should show the code that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your debugging details.  We should be able to copy what you have and follow your instructions to make it fail in the way you described.  Please edit the question to include all relevant information.

Comment: sorry for this, but now I have debugged it and solved thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

As the error says you need to order before using inequality operation.

```
...
const query = geoCollection.orderBy("requestStatus").where("requestStatus", "!=", "Pending")
...
```

Comment: ya but it didn't work, so, 180 rotate the approach and now i am checking with equality instead of inequality,  thanks